# Artifactory does not reflect a change of the Custom Base URL

Tags: artifactory

I installed JFrog Artifactory via Helm. When I first-time log in, I saw the following configuration of URL to File.
[image]
The URL has HTTPS and port 80, which is wrong.
Then I configured the Custom Base URL to be correct.
[image]
Even if I created a new Maven repo using the quick start wizard, the URL has still port 80 in the path.
[image]
The HTTPS protocol and port 80 cause, that the URL is not accessible.
Am I doing something wrong or is it a bug? How to set up the Custom URL to a correct value?
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that I forwarded HTTPS traffic to HTTP. It was working but produced the issue described above.

The solution for me was to forward the HTTPS traffic from outside to HTTPS port on the `service/artifactory-artifactory-nginx` and add the following annotation to the ingress:

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: "HTTPS"
```